# How to set REMOTE_ADDR to HTTP_X_REAL_IP?

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, cpanel, varnish

I've tried many ways set the REMOTE_ADDR (showing my server IP) as HTTP_X_REAL_IP (showing the visitor's IP).

I'm using cPanel with Apache + NGINX + Varnish.

What is the best method for the REMOTE_ADDR take the actual visitor's IP with NGINX + Varnish?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure in what order you have the different layers, assuming Internet -> NGINX -> Varnish -> Apache?

But in each layer you have to explicit forward the client-ip to ensure you get it onto the apache layer.
Note, that i would use the standardised X-Forwarded-For header instead of HTTP_X_REAL_IP

For Nginx

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

For Varnish

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # Add a unique header containing the client address    
 if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
   set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  } else {
   set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
  }
  # [...]
}
```

Within Apache log files you then can retrieve the X-Forwarded-For header (which contains the original client-ip as initial received by nginx) using

```
%{X-Forwarded-For}i
```